# grouping latest time with correct data from same row

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to get the lastest time (end_time) for each day and then post it with the correct trans_num (id#) and log_message....kinda works but having some issues..

here's a pic of the data:

[image]

here's my code:

```
SELECT max(start_time) as start_time, max(end_time) as end_time, uid, trans_num, log_message FROM table1 WHERE uid='admin' AND start_time BETWEEN '2013-09-29 00:00:00' AND '2013-10-05 23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(end_time)
```

the result is:

[image]

The correct latest times are being selected but the trans_num is wrong for 2013-10-02... its suppose to be 757 and log_message is wrong as well... it should be "jj"

can anyone help me?

Comment: max start time and max end time can correspond to different trans_num's. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to match your selected `end_time` with the appropriate `trans_num` and `log_message`. You can do it by `JOIN`ing your result with the initial table:

```
SELECT  
    a.st,
    a.et,
    t1.trans_num,
    t1.log_message
FROM
    (SELECT 
        max(start_time) as st, 
        max(end_time) as et 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE uid='admin' AND start_time BETWEEN '2013-09-29 00:00:00' AND '2013-10-05 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY DATE(end_time)) a
    JOIN 
    table1 t1 ON a.et=t1.end_time
```

Comment: Getting an error with this... #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: @rubberchicken on which line?

Comment: near 'FROM table1 WHERE uid='admin' AND start_time BETWEEN '2013-09-29 0' at line 10

Comment: @rubberchicken typo - there was extra comma after `et`